# Using RxJs/Reactive programming - how can I get a related entity?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have two entities: `Organization` and `User`. In my component, I have access to the currently authenticated user like this:

```
// component.ts

public authenticatedUser$ = this._authService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
        tap((user) => {
            console.log('authenticatedUser$: ', user); // {id: '123', organizationId: '456',...}
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
```

What I am trying to do is get the organization that this user belongs to. I've been trying different variations of this without much success:

```
// component.ts

// private _organizationSubject:Subject<IOrganization>();
// public organization$ = this._organizationiSubject.asObservable();

public organization$ = this.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
        map(
            (user) =>
                tap((user) => {
                    console.log('user', user);
                })
            // this._organizationService.getOrganization(user.organizationId)
            // this._organizationSubject.next([--response from service--]);
        ),
        catchError((err) => {
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
    
...


ngOnInit(): void {
  // actual call(s) need to go here...

    this.authenticatedUser$
            .pipe(
                tap((user) => console.log('user: ', user)),
                tap((user) => {
                    this._organizationService.getOrganization(
                        user.organizationId
                    );
                }),
                catchError((err) => {
                    return EMPTY;
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
}
```

I realize my `???map` is likely incorrect as well. I've been watching a lot of Deborah Kurata's videos & trying to make my data stream mimic her action streams. I am working with two data streams as I am always working with an authenticated user. There is no "interaction" to get these values.

In following her advice:

```
// what do we want (organization)
// what do we have (org id)
// when do we want it (when page loads e.g. OnInit)
```

Doing this a procedural way would be quite simple, however I'm really struggling with making it work in a declarative way.

**EDIT**

I have something working, but still struggling outside of just guessing what is happening.

```
// component.ts

public authenticatedUser$ = this._authService.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
    
...


ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authenticatedUser$
            .pipe(
                switchMap((user) =>
                    this._organizationService
                        .getOrganization(user.organizationId)
                        .pipe(tap((data) => console.log('data: ', data))) // {id: '123', name: 'My Org', ...}
                ),
                catchError((err) => {
                    return EMPTY;
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
    }
```

Since I am using `switchMap` will I also need to unsubscribe? Perhaps in the `ngOnDestory` method or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last code posted is fine, it should work. You could use `mergeMap` or `switchMap`, it depends on your needs, `switchMap` discards the current value if another one is emitted, and `mergeMap` works with every new value emitted.

Giving you an analogy for this, you are eating a meal while using `switchMap`, suddenly, the waitress comes with a new meal, then, you proceed to discard your current meal, and start eating the new one, it doesn't matter if you finished your first meal, you just discard it. If you were using `mergeMap`, you would eat both meals...

If you were using `exhaustMap` while eating the first meal, and the second meal comes, you would ignore this second one and incoming ones until you finish the current meal, and those ignored meals are lost... and lastly, if you were using `concatMap` while eating your fist meal, and the second one comes at you, you would wait until you finish your first meal, and **only** then, you start eating the second one...

If you don't want to handle the `subscription`, then just store it in an `Observable` the result of `authenticatedUser$` and the service call `getOrganization` for then `subscribe` using the `async` pipe, which in this case, is the reactive approach:

```js
userOrganization$!: Observable<SomeType>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userOrganization$ = this.authenticatedUser$.pipe(
    switchMap((user) =>  
       this._organizationService.getOrganization(user.organizationId))
  );
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(userOrganization$ | async) as userOrganization">
 <div>
   <p>{{ userOrganization.id }}</p>
   <p>{{ userOrganization.name }}</p>
   ...
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

Also, if you want to do it in a procedural way, you should store the subscription, and then destroy it in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook:

```
private sub = new Subscription();


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub.add(
    this.authenticatedUser$.pipe(...).subscribe();
  );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.sub?.unsubscribe();
}
```

The `tap` operator is used for handling side effects, so in this case, it is correct the way you are using it, you are `console.log`ging in this case.

If you have an `observable` and you want to use `tap`, you can do it directly without using `map`

```js
// there is no need for using map here
myObservable$.pipe(tap((data) => console.log('The data: ', data))).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh - this is SO HELPFUL!! Your analogy was really great. I could visualize the different operators much easier. I will be updating my code accordingly. Using my example above, I won't really ever output to a template. I will be passing the `orgId` as an input to another component. This gives me such a great place to work from. Thank you!